# jQuery is not running on Yii 2

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i copy a code from net to make a Dialog Popup form .
the code is :

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog functionality</title>
    <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        .ui-widget-header,.ui-state-default, ui-button{
            background:#b9cd6d;
            border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
            });
            $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="dialog-1" title="Dialog Title goes here...">This my first jQuery UI Dialog!</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
</body>
</html>
```

i create a view in Yii 2 and copy this code there but the output is not running , output is just a button a paragraf like normal button and paragraf and there is no popuo and dialog !!1
what should i do?

Comment: make sure you don't have any console errors

Comment: @madalinivascu i didn't change the code , i just Crt C + Crt V :)))  the code was running well on the tutorial site i read .

Comment: you can try to add only BODY part in view file because other this will be come from layout section. and include js and css which mentioned in code at view file if you want to just test that dialog is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

the view is rendered inside the layout
you find the layout in app/views/layout

Did you copy the complete quellcode into a view ? than maybe there are some javascript loading tags in your layout too

look at the quellcode in your browser to check this

try to put this part into layout

if

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        .ui-widget-header,.ui-state-default, ui-button{
            background:#b9cd6d;
            border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
            });
            $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this part into your view

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="dialog-1" title="Dialog Title goes here...">This my first jQuery UI Dialog!</div>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

if you have chrome or firefox browser press control+shift+i and check the quellcode
if this is still correct html

or maybe you have a tree like this

```
<html>
<head>
 ......
</head>

<body>


    <html>
    <head>
     ......
    </head>

    <body>
     ......
    </body>

    </html>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i think there is some js loading tag in my layout , is it a problem? then shoud i disable or remove the defualt js from my yii 2 ? @ThomasRohde

Comment: if you try a example source without necessary changes than it will not work. add the javascript loading from the example in to your layout and remove header and body tags in example ..

Comment: i'm sorry o didn't got it ! if you meant i copy this code to an empty html file , i did it again and it did run well !!! @ThomasRohde

Comment: i Check the quellcode , i can see my quellcode in code when the page is running !! @ThomasRohde

Comment: Ok, please copy the complete generated running html quellcode to your question, not the example

Comment: but i did it before !!! i only write the code in my question to "/views/site/blawblaw.php" as some veiw file !!!! @ThomasRohde

Comment: It look like there is nothing wrong with the code. It is happening due to conflict of some JQuery having older version with the current JQuery you are adding, I will suggest to register these Js Files into asset and then give it try.

Comment: sorry, maybe i am not able to explain very good. please run yout example in your browser like you did befor and it didnt work. than open the sourcecode from your browser and copy that here so we can see the result of rendered html.